# jQuery UI Touch Punch draggable()

Tags: jquery, touch, jquery-ui-touch-punch

In my application I use drag&drop which I aslo want to implement on mobile devices. I was thinking about using JQuery Ui touch punch like this:

```
  var thumb = document.createElement("img");
  $(thumb).draggable({containment: "html"});
```

The problem is that my image is dragged only in the scope of its parent (see attached image) not on the whole page. I've tried changing containment options but the problem seems to be elsewhere.
[image]

CSS:

```
html, body { 
   height: 100%;
   background: black;
   margin:0; padding:0;
   overflow:hidden;
}
//one parent
.dhThumbOuter {
    float: left;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #4d4d4d;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #4d4d4d;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #4d4d4d;
    border:solid gray 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    font-size: smaller;
    position:relative;
    border : solid gray 2px;

}
//other parrent
.dhThumbImage {
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 0;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute;
}​
```

Javascript:

```
   var thout = createElement("div", "dhThumbOuter dhRounded");
            container.appendChild(thout);
            var thinner = createElement("div", "dhThumbImage dhRounded");
            thout.appendChild(thinner);
            thinner.appendChild(thumb); //my image
```

Comment: HTML,CSS regarding the image, its parent and the page?

Comment: `.dhThumbOuter{position:relative;}` see that? That's the natural container of your image. `postion:absolute` elements comply to their `position:relative` parents

Comment: Removing that propertie doesn't help

Comment: Can you provide http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: The issue was in the overflow porperties.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `helper: clone` property on `draggable()` so that the image "breaks out" of it's container when dragged.

See the official jQuery UI draggable docs here: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper

Comment: I've tried to replicate your situation in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QAKeR/ (I'm using p tags instead of img tags for the draggable element). Try dragging the different elements to see the different behaviour, with and without the `clone` helper.

Comment: The issue was in the overflow porperties.

Comment: I was looking for the solution how the draggable objects to return to its original position and came across your example $(yourobject).draggable({
            revert: "invalid"
        });

So thank you friend that you helped me! Now my draggable objects return automatically to its original positions when not dropped! Thumbs up! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add custom helper

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
  zIndex: 20,
  drag: function(event){...},
  helper: function(){
    $("#outerElement").append($("#draggable").clone().attr('id', 'itWorks'))
    return $("#itWorks");
  },
})
```

where outerElement is the element which contains your draggable and drop element as well